# Hashtags in Newsfeeds show up as GUID

Tags: 2013, newsfeed, hashtags

When posting and using a hashtag in both my test and production 2013 environments, the hashtag shows up as the tag GUID, rather than the hashtag itself.

After a refresh of the page, the hashtag is there, but it's not clickable, and can only be followed. I'm at a loss on this one. ULS is not throwing me any bones...

[image]